# How to conduct significance testing for percent outcome based on summary statistics only?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, percentage, beta-regression

I have three groups A, B, and C, with corresponding sample size. I have gender variable as a binary variable, with M vs. F. For each group, it's summarized into "percentage woman". I only have the following summary statistics:

```
                    Group A     Group B     Group C
N                   1000        1020        100
Percentage woman    57%         20%         40%
```

Based only on this information, is it possible to conduct significance test to see if the "percentage women" is statistically different between the three groups. My understanding is ANOVA is not a good test since it's dealing with percentage, and I can't conduct the supposed logistic regression since I don't have the raw data. I wonder if this is the case for beta-regression?

Also, I am wondering if I can re-calculate the figures into count of M and count of F for each group, and then perform a chi-squared test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is ANOVA is not a good test since it's dealing with percentage

You are correct. An ANOVA would be used if you had a continuous dependent variable. Since your dependent variable is categorical (woman vs. not woman), an ANOVA is not appropriate here.

> I can't conduct the supposed logistic regression since I don't have the raw data

You could recreate raw data, based on the information you have. You can make one column be called `woman` and coded `yes` or `no`, and then another column denoting the `group`, being `a`, `b`, or `c`:

```
# make columns of yes and no for each group
group_a <- c(rep("yes", .57 * 1000), rep("no", .43 * 1000))
group_b <- c(rep("yes", .20 * 1020), rep("no", .80 * 1020))
group_c <- c(rep("yes", .40 * 100), rep("no", .60 * 100))

# put into data frame
dat <- data.frame(
  woman = factor(c(group_a, group_b, group_c)),
  group = factor(c(rep("a", 1000), rep("b", 1020), rep("c", 100)))
)
```

Then, you can run a logistic regression:

```
model <- glm(woman ~ group, dat, family = binomial("logit"))
summary(model)
```

Which will return:

```
Call:
glm(formula = woman ~ group, family = binomial("logit"), data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2992  -0.6681  -0.6681   1.0603   1.7941  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.28185    0.06387   4.413 1.02e-05 ***
groupb      -1.66815    0.10103 -16.511  < 2e-16 ***
groupc      -0.68732    0.21388  -3.213  0.00131 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2823.7  on 2119  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2522.1  on 2117  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2528.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The intercept is the log-odds of being a woman for people in Group A. You can see this by taking the inverse logit of the intercept and seeing that it equals the proportion of women in Group A:

```
> exp(0.28185) / (1 + exp(0.28185))
[1] 0.5699997
```

The `groupb` and `groupc` coefficients are both the comparison in log-odds from Group A. If you wanted to compare `groupb` to `groupc`, I know you could get the difference between the two conditions and then use `vcov(model)`, but I can't remember right now how to calculate the standard error between two different regression coefficients.

(*Note: I'd appreciate it if someone could point out in a comment below how I could get the SE for the difference between coefficients `groupb` and `groupc`.)*

So instead, you could just change the reference category to get the difference between Group B and Group C:

```
summary(glm(woman ~ relevel(group, ref = "b"), dat, family = binomial("logit")))
```

Which returns:

```
Call:
glm(formula = woman ~ relevel(group, ref = "b"), family = binomial("logit"), 
    data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2992  -0.6681  -0.6681   1.0603   1.7941  

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                -1.38629    0.07828 -17.710  < 2e-16 ***
relevel(group, ref = "b")a  1.66815    0.10103  16.511  < 2e-16 ***
relevel(group, ref = "b")c  0.98083    0.21862   4.486 7.24e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2823.7  on 2119  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2522.1  on 2117  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2528.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The last coefficient, the one with `c`, shows you the last pairwise comparison.

> I wonder if this is the case for beta-regression?

Beta regression assumes that your response, conditioned on the predictors, is beta distributed. This is not the case with categorical dependent variables (as you do in your example). The beta regression is most used for instances when your dependent variable is bounded between 0 and 1, like ratios or proportions. [(Although I think it can be used in interesting ways for other types of responses).](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58a7d1e52994ca398697a621/t/5a2ebc43e4966b0fab6b02de/1513012293857/betareg_politics.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Mark. I wonder if I can recalculate data into count data (as mentioned in my question), and do a chi-squared test?

Comment: You could translate your percentages into counts and then put them into a contingency table, which is easy to calculate a chi-square statistic for. There are lots of calculators out there for doing so (http://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/chisquare2/Default2.aspx). I did it like this: https://imgur.com/PvYmckJ. But the logistic regression should be about the same thing; I personally find the logistic regression to be more interpretable, as the chi-square from contingency tables don't always give you the pairwise comparisons you're interested in.

Comment: I would not call it "count data," though. That refers to the dependent variable being counts of some event (e.g., how many times someones visits the emergency room). The cells in a contingency table are counts, but it will confuse people by calling it "count data." That's just a jargony thing that might cause confusion.

Comment: Just realized I messed up in adding the counts in that imgur link, but you get the picture.

Comment: Just following up on beta regression. If we consider only the summary statistics and say not reconstructing the raw data or transforming it back to 'count', would it be appropriate to use beta regression when you consider the percent woman as an outcome variable? Since it ranges from 0 to 1.0, would beta reg be fine?

Comment: If you had a bunch of groups (say, 150 groups) that had proportions of women, you could look at the relationship between characteristics of the group and proportion of women in the group. But you wouldn't be able to compare the proportions of women between any specific group.

Comment: Instead of relying on asymptotic inference - as in the logistic regression or the chi-squared test - you could also use exact inference for this two-way contingency table, e.g., Fisher's exact test (`fisher.test` in R). In such a large data set it won't make any difference but it might for smaller numbers of observations.